# Is it possible to start a shinyWidgets' awesomeRatio input with no option selected?

Tags: r, input, shiny, char

I would like to use the `selected = character(0)` parameter in `awesomeRatio()` input from [shinyWidgets](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/awesomeRadio.html) package, just as I would use it in `radioButtons()` input (Shiny's default), but the option does not seem to be supported.

MWE:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    awesomeRadio(inputId = "id1", label = "Make a choice:", #selected = character(0),
                 choices = c("graphics", "ggplot2")),
    radioButtons(inputId = "id2", label = "Make a choice:", selected = character(0),
                 choices = c("graphics", "ggplot2")),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$res1 <- renderPrint(input$id1)
    output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$id2)
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Comment: `NULL` does not seem to be supported either. Try `""`

Comment: That was indeed what I finally came up with, but used a dummy `"."` since the `""` alone was causing me a weird layout. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nicer if there were a way to hide the dummy choice...